# lxde stop auto maximize vertical when moving window to right edge of screen

Tags: ubuntu, x11, lxde

I am running lxle version 14.04.3. I would like to stop lxde from maximizing my window vertically when I drag a window to the right edge of the screen. Does anyone know how to change this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Preferences->Default applications for LXSession or
   lxsession-default-apps
2. Press autostart
3. Uncheck the line opensnap -d (or remove it)
4. log out/ login. Other things may work as well.

The above can be done by editing the file ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart

Lubuntu may also be LXDE in other configurations.

I didn't even know opensnap was running.

Comment: Another thing I didn't know was running was a hot corner script called hotcorn. If you move your cursor to the top left, it takes your windows, vertical maxes them and tiles them across the X axis. One more thing to remove from autostart.